# apply button in joomla for form

Tags: joomla

My form currently has a save button but no apply button. I tried to insert one but it does the same thing as save. Any ideas? Here is the code:

```
    <div class="formelm-buttons">
        <button type="button" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('propform.save')">
            <?php echo JText::_('JSAVE') ?>
        </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('propform.cancel')">
            <?php echo JText::_('JCANCEL') ?>
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: i want to click the apply button and stay on that page instead of returning to the menu

Comment: We need more details e.g. Where's the definition of the “Apply” button, how is your controller handling this? Etc

Comment: If your controller extends from JControllerForm, it should handle this for you.

Comment: it does extend the jcontroller form - here is the code for the save function (i think)

Comment: public function save($key = null, $urlVar = 'id')
 {
  $result = parent::save($key, $urlVar);

  // If ok, redirect to the return page.
  if ($result) {
   $this->setRedirect($this->getReturnPage());
  }

  return $result;
 }

Comment: Do I have to creat a similar apply function? does anyone know what code i can use to create that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short:**

Remove `$this->setRedirect($this->getReturnPage());` from your save function.

**Reason it breaks apply:**

So this is the function from your comment:

```php
public function save($key = null, $urlVar = 'id')
{
    $result = parent::save($key, $urlVar); // If ok, redirect to the return page.
    if ($result) {
        $this->setRedirect($this->getReturnPage());
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I understand this function is placed inside a controller which extends JControllerForm.
Now, this is pretty badly documented but: **JControllerForm::save($key, $urlVar) will set the redirect for you.**

This means that when you run `$this->setRedirect($this->getReturnPage());` you will override what JControllerForm has already done for you. The difference between *save* and *apply* is where to redirect after a successful save.

So if you remove that *setRedirect*, the apply should start working (if everything else is alright). Also if you have constructed the table for this save correctly the $urlVar parameter will be set for you. So if that is the case, you don't need to override *save* at all.

Comment: thanks for your help i have removed that bit and added this into my form   <button type="button" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('propform.apply')">
                <?php echo JText::_('JAPPLY') ?>
            </button>